# What Caused the Cabin Font to be Dropped in This Enumeration?

Tags: macros, enumerate, enumitem, quotation, cabin

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=.5in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=4.95in \textwidth 3.00in


\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} % replaces obsolete times package.

\usepackage{xparse}
\definecolor{granite}{RGB}{103,103,103}


\newlist{advice}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[advice]{
  label=\formatadvicenumber{\textbf{\color{granite}\arabic*}},
  ref=\arabic*,
  leftmargin=1.25em,
  labelsep=.55em, 
  itemsep=1.00em, 
  wide=0pt, % Prevents numbers from entering the left-hand margin.
  resume,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatadvicenumber}{m}{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr1.35\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\LARGE #1}%
}

\usepackage{scalefnt}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont---}}

\newcommand{\funnyquoteEN}[2]{%
  \par{\parindent=0pt #1\par}\nopagebreak
  \vspace*{-7pt}\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash\fontfamily{qtm}\selectfont\textit{\textbf{#2}}%
}


\newcommand{\funnyquote}[2]{%
  \par\scalefont{1.0}{#1}\\[-10.5pt]\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash{\fontfamily{qtm}\selectfont\textit{\textbf{#2}}}%

}

\setlength\itemsep{4em}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{advice}
\item \funnyquote{A quote}{Author}

\item \funnyquote{A quote}{Author}

\item 
\funnyquoteEN{
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1

\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}}{Author}


\item \funnyquote{A quote}{Author}
\end{advice}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: Why is the fourth item (quote portion) not displayed with the *cabin* font as the previous ones are?

*Remarks:*
In the code, I have defined two quotation commands: `\fancyquote` which here produces the 1st, 2nd, and 4th items; and `\funnyquoteEN` which handles an `enumerate` environment within the quotation---which produced the third item in the MWE display.

And, I have both of these contained within an "\advice" enumeration which produces large, fancy item numbers in the general enumeration.